# Find all timestamp in textfile and convert this timestamp in (UTC-5) with SED or AWK linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, timezone

I have the following problem in linux ubuntu,
I need find all string timestamp(UTC) in my text file and convert in timestamp with timezone UTC -5 using bash script

I need script using sed or awk

### Original textfile with timestamp in UTC is:

FINE: 2021/10/24 14:02:04,SAT:
FINE: 2021/10/24 14:02:04,SAT:
FINE: 2021/10/24 14:02:04,SAT:
INFO: 2021/10/24 14:02:04,GRDi
FINE: 2021/10/24 14:02:04,GRDi
FINER: 2021/10/24 14:02:05,GRD
FINE: 2021/10/24 14:02:05,x,DB
FINE: 2021/10/24 14:10:44,SERV
CONFIG: 2021/10/24 14:10:44,x,
FINER: 2021/10/24 14:10:44,SAT
FINE: 2021/10/24 14:10:44,SAT:

### And I need convert timestamp (UTC-5) and outfile would be this:

FINE: 2021/10/24 09:02:04,SAT:
FINE: 2021/10/24 09:02:04,SAT:
FINE: 2021/10/24 09:02:04,SAT:
INFO: 2021/10/24 09:02:04,GRDi
FINE: 2021/10/24 09:02:04,GRDi
FINER: 2021/10/24 09:02:05,GRD
FINE: 2021/10/24 09:02:05,x,DB
FINE: 2021/10/24 09:10:44,SERV
CONFIG: 2021/10/24 09:10:44,x,
FINER: 2021/10/24 09:10:44,SAT
FINE: 2021/10/24 09:10:44,SAT:

Thanks for your help...

Comment: An example of exactly how you want your data to look after processing will help people
answer the question for you. Since then there is no ambiguity and people can build a good answer. Cheers!

Comment: please update the question with the timezone under which the current date/time data was generated otherwise it won't be possible to determine the offset from UTC-5

Comment: Question is unlcear at the moment - please provide an example of what you would like the output to look like and wether or not you want to change the numerical values or just add the timezone at the end

Comment: @Rolando Diaz ... are you still around? :)

Comment: @tink thank for help me, your script  is perfect!! very Good!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of achieving this ... save the *script* as e.g. minus5h.awk,

```
{
    one = gensub(/^([^ ]+ ).*/, "\\1", 1, $0).    # store the beginning of line 
    rest = gensub(/[^,]+,(.*)$/, "\\1", 1, $0).   # store the rest of the line after the time-spec
    split($2, a, "/")                             # split the date into chunks

    split(gensub(/([^,]+).*/,"\\1",1,$3), b, ":") # split the time into chunks
    c = mktime(a[1] " " a[2] " " a[3] " " b[1] " " b[2] " " b[3]) - 18000  # convert the date into seconds and subtract 5 hours
    printf "%s%s,%s\n", one, strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", c), rest       # print everything with the new timestamp
}
```

and then run it like so:

```
awk -f minus5h.awk logfile
FINE: 2021/10/24 09:02:04,SAT:
FINE: 2021/10/24 09:02:04,SAT:
FINE: 2021/10/24 09:02:04,SAT:
INFO: 2021/10/24 09:02:04,GRDi
FINE: 2021/10/24 09:02:04,GRDi
FINER: 2021/10/24 09:02:05,GRD
FINE: 2021/10/24 09:02:05,x,DB
FINE: 2021/10/24 09:10:44,SERV
CONFIG: 2021/10/24 09:10:44,x,
FINER: 2021/10/24 09:10:44,SAT
FINE: 2021/10/24 09:10:44,SAT:
```

Comment: This Script is perfect, thks for the solution!

Comment: You're welcome, it was fun (fue un placer ;)) @RolandoDiaz